# How do I tell OS X to never include certain folders in Recent Places on Open/Save dialogs?

Tags: macos

When I tried to save a document I noticed a recent section and folders listed I don't want people to see.

[image]

How I can either get OS X to never add these to Recent Places, or if that's not possible then turn off Recent Places period?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it on a per directory basis. What you can do is:

1. Clear the current list with the following command in Terminal:

   `defaults delete -g NSNavRecentPlaces`

   Then repeat it each time you want the list to be cleared.
2. Disable saving the Recent Places history completely with:

   `defaults write -g NSNavRecentPlacesLimit -int 0`